# how to get selected spinner item and send through SMS

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am Android Newbie here I do not know how to pass the selected spinner text to pass to SMS as SMS text to send to selected number by pressing a button. I am happy if someone can teach me here.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity { //all starts here
    String[] location;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        location = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.location_array);
        Spinner s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, location);
        s1.setAdapter(adapter);
        s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
            {
                int index = arg0.getSelectedItemPosition();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have selected " + location[index], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0){}

        });
    }

        public void onClick(View v) {          //<--**HERE IS THE PROBLEM**
        sendSMS("5556", "+location [index]"); //<--**HERE IS THE PROBLEM**
    }



    //?sends an SMS message to another device?
    private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
    {
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
    }

}
```

//-must end here

Comment: put this sendSMS("5556", "+location [index]"); in public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
            {
                int index = arg0.getSelectedItemPosition();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have selected " + location[index], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

Comment: @Ken Please see my answer and if you have any issues regarding that then tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Save Selected value in one String Variable and then Send into SMS and another option is declare `int index` variable outside  `onItemSelected()` function, sorry for my bad english communication but it will solve your problem, please see below link for more information.

[Spinners in Android](http://creatiosoft.com/forum/showthread.php?tid=135&pid=143#pid143)

and Use below code instead of your code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity { //all starts here
    String[] location;
    int index;
    String mSelectedItem;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        location = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.location_array);
        Spinner s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, location);
        s1.setAdapter(adapter);
        s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
            {
                index = arg0.getSelectedItemPosition();
                //OR you can also store selected item using below line.
                mSelectedItem=arg0.getSelectedItem().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have selected " + location[index], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0){

            }

        });
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        sendSMS("5556", location [index]);
        //OR you can also send sms using below code.
        sendSMS("5556", mSelectedItem);
    }    

    //?sends an SMS message to another device?
    private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
    {
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Dipak, can you give example of code? Thanks. I am trying hard to solve this for atleast 12hours already.

Comment: Thanks Dipak. declare 'int index' globally solved the problem. Thank again!

Answer (score 1):

put this `sendSMS("5556", "+location [index]");` in

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
            {

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have selected " + location[arg2], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                sendSMS("5556", location[arg2]);
            }
```

Comment: I had tried this but not successful. It still send +location [index] but the index was replaced with a character which is not selected from the Spinner menu

Comment: @Ken check my edit now actually i thought you are taking index from arguments but it was not the case the argument int arg2, is the index of the selected item.

Comment: receiver side it received unwanted text still, ie.: + location[ > 

I am thinking of assigning the selected spinner(from string-array), then push a button to send the sms, the receiver should only receive the value from the string-array only. 

And I am no idea how to place the sendSMS( ) at which place

Comment: @Ken check now i think you are selecting predefine message to send right?

Comment: Yes, exactly, I'm trying to passing to the sendSMS( ) but I purely believe anything under " xxx " will be treated as text

Comment: Thanks Akki, the problem solved, it needs to declare the index outside the onItemSelected() function as mentioned by Dipak in the next comment. Thank Akki for the ideas and thoughts.